# Hyperledger Fabric - npm install dependency error "grpc@1.17.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`"

Tags: npm, hyperledger-fabric

Hyperledger Fabric Commercial paper example (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/tutorial/commercial_paper.html) is giving me this error when I try to install the Magneto application dependencies using npm install.

Log:

```
1359 verbose stack Error: grpc@1.17.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
1359 verbose stack Exit status 1
1359 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/home/hyperfabric/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:301:16)
1359 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:200:13)
1359 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/hyperfabric/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
1359 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:200:13)
1359 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
1359 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:283:5)
1360 verbose pkgid grpc@1.17.0
1361 verbose cwd /home/hyperfabric/go/src/testFabric/fabric-samples/commercial-paper/organization/magnetocorp/application
1362 verbose Linux 4.15.0-51-generic
1363 verbose argv "/home/hyperfabric/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/bin/node" "/home/hyperfabric/.nvm/versions/node/v12.4.0/bin/npm" "install"
1364 verbose node v12.4.0
1365 verbose npm  v6.9.0
1366 error code ELIFECYCLE
1367 error errno 1
1368 error grpc@1.17.0 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build --library=static_library`
1368 error Exit status 1
1369 error Failed at the grpc@1.17.0 install script.
1369 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
1370 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: There is [an issue on Github](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-node/issues/693#issuecomment-463555352) regarding this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You are using an unsupported version of Node.js to build the project, Fabric currently supports Node builds with a version on 8.9.x, I recommend you take a look at the prereqs here and make sure you have satisfied them all:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/prereqs.html

Comment: Coming back to this, I probably could have explained better. The gRPC dep is pinned on a specific version, you were using Node 12 to try and build the native node module which was pinned on a version meant to be built with Node 8 or Node 10. I went out and confirmed if I pulled the version of the SDK from this time period and built it with Node 12, this error happens (expectedly), Node 10 and 8 worked perfectly. We expect this failure would have happened on Node 12. Yes, gRPC does have a build problem, but until you use the correct version of node, we can't be sure you are affected by it.